# How to use State with Pipes?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have a function with a type `Map Int String -> Proxy () a () Void IO b`.  Right now it `await`s, does whatever with the value it got, and then re-calls itself.  I'd like to change it to use `State (Map Int String)` instead of having that passed as an argument, so I can just use `forever` and don't need to have every branch remember to recurse.  I get that I need to use `StateT` to combine `State` with another monad, but I don't understand where in that type signature the `StateT` belongs, or whether or not I need to `lift` functions like `get`.  What is the correct type for a function that is both a `State (Map Int String)` and a `Proxy () a () Void IO b`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note: `Proxy () a () Void = Consumer a`, so I will refer to it as a `Consumer` for this answer.

The simple way is to put your `StateT` monad transformer layer outside of the `Consumer` layer and then run it immediately.  Here is an example:

```
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict
import Pipes

example :: (Show a) => Consumer a IO r
example = flip evalStateT 0 $ forever $ do
    -- Inside here we are using `StateT Int (Consumer a IO) r`
    a <- lift await
    n <- get
    lift $ lift $ putStrLn $ "Received value #" ++ show n ++ ": " ++ show a
    put (n + 1)
```

... and this is how it behaves in action:

```
>>> runEffect $ each ["Test", "ABC"] >-> example
Received value #0: "Test"
Received value #1: "ABC"
```